# Realm select records from two tables which are matched (Join)

Tags: android, nosql, realm

I am quite new to Realm-android, i have two tables `Prospects` and `ProspectCallDetails` both have field `token`. I want to retrieve all `Prospects` which  `token` matched with `ProspectCallDetails` token.

```
 public class Prospects extends RealmObject
 {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int  ProspectId; 
    private String token;
    .
    .
 }

public class ProspectCallDetails extends RealmObject
{  
     @PrimaryKey 
    private int ProspectCallId;
    private String token;
    .
    .
 }
```

I want to retrieve all Prospects which token is matched with the ProspectCallDetails token,

Like In Sql :

```
Select prop.* from Prospects prop Join PropsectCallDetails callD on prop.token=callD.token
```

Comment: You can't do that, you need to have a `RealmList<ProspectCallDetails>` for these two classes to be related.

Comment: Ok, means its all about how we maintain the data structure